# Chrome slower when console open at page load

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

`1 Load page with webgl` --fast.

`2 Open console` --slower, 60fps but spikes of much lower

`3 Refresh with console open` -- Page starts to drop to a crawl, like not many fps.

`4 close and reopen console log` -- Page responds similar to #2

What is causing me to need to re-open console.log -- syntax highlighting or async debugging?

Comment: Without screenshots of the fps timeline and other specifics I'd say I've never seen such behavior so I'd recommend investigating whether it happens on all sites, whether it depends on the presence of certain extensions (disable all or make a new user profile or open an incognito window).

Comment: Just checked a few sites from [this list](http://www.creativebloq.com/3d/30-amazing-examples-webgl-action-6142954) on 2560x1600 fullscreen and windowed with `chrome://flags/#show-fps-counter` enabled - can't reproduce the problem. With an exception of small spikes during my actions it's always 60fps. `chrome://gpu` state is full hardware acceleration for everything except `rasterization` as it's buggy on my nVidia.

Comment: I have the same or a similar problem: Without developer tools the WebGL animations run fluently. After opening developer tools, and especially when logging a lot of test output to the console, the CPU usage of the machine (in the windows task manager) goes to 100% and the webgl animation drops frames. I am using a slow 9 years old CPU, on a recent CPU I do not experience this behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had also problem with slow page loads when Devtools was open. In my case images and ajax loads were extreme slow. The only way I could speed is up is to `disable async stack traces` in the `Devtools` preferences.

[image: Devtools Preferences > Disable Stack Traces]

Comment: Oh that's where they put that setting... it used to be in sources I think.. async debugging was off by default.. guess it's on now.

Comment: Worth noting to disable your breakpoints, having a conditional breakpoint may have a huge impact if it's run over very often

Comment: I have the same issue (just redrawing canvas without webgl usage) but turning this off does not solve my case. Does anyone know other clues?

Answer (score 4):

Seems to work seamlessly when `async debugging` is DISABLED ( it's usually disabled, I had to turn it on a while ago ), within the `sources` tab in `developer tools`