# Why do scripts run so much more slowly when the browser console is open?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I recently did a performance test with some Javascript that does a lot of data processing in the browser, and noticed that the time it takes for a particular task is much longer (3.5-4x) with the browser console open than it is without, even though nothing is printed to the browser console (prior to or during the task) and there is no filter on new messages.  The processing does not make a lot of DOM changes either.  The Network tab was not active or recording traffic during this time, and there wasn't any network traffic anyway. No breakpoints are set anywhere, in active or inactive code, and there are no debugger statements in the code.

Comment: Do you have breakpoints set anywhere? Even ones that are disabled or not being hit can affect overall performance.

Comment: Good question!  No breakpoints are set anywhere, in active or inactive code. Question edited to reflect that.

Comment: Try [disabling async stack traces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65950401)?

Comment: In which of the many browsers?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Probably multiple, but the multiple google chrome tags on the question should indicate one in particular

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I think that's worthy of expansion into an Answer - it seems to bring the difference down to a factor <2, but changing this setting seems to dramatically increase the probability of out of memory crashes that I can't yet get past (with async stack traces disabled & DevTools open) to test more rigorously.

Answer (score 0):

it might be due to your preferences open you devtools click on settings is the   ⚙️
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfOkg.png)

on your left side "gear" I think thats who is it call... sorry for my english I am a ESL under network section you'll probably have checked the option disable cache while devtools open... or something like that

if it is not checked then go to Network tab and search for "disable cache" uncheck it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8Pvr.png)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Yes, cache is disabled while devtools are open, but there's no network traffic during the long-processing portion, so I don't think use of the cache or not would have an impact.